# How to use shared preference in tabhost on android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, android-tabhost

Can any one give me java code to the below emulator images needs?

[image]

The above emulator image is just getting the input from the user and showing the answer in the edittext of the same page.But i need to show that answer on the Tabhost ( which wants to be on the next page ) like the below image..

[image]

Thanks a lot!..

Comment: am I the only one that did not understand the question?

Comment: Ovidiu Latcu Plz visit my question again,i've demanded my needs to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you start the next TabActivity?

When you create *Intent* for starting *YourTabActivity* you can put **answer** in this *Intent* like:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourTabActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("answer", answer);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your *FirstActivity* in **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** method you can get your answer, like:

```
final double answer = getParent().getIntent().getDoubleExtra("answer", 0);
```

or, if your **answer** put as *String*:

```
final double answer = getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("answer");
```

When you get your **answer** you can insert it anywhere in layout of that activity.

For sending primitive and serializeable data between Atstivites use [Intent.putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put the data from the first `Activity` on the `Intent` you are using to start your `TabActivity`. This is really basic `Android` stuff, so please look at some tutorials first : [Android Intents](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html).

Comment: Ovidiu Latcu Actually my first page is going to get the input from the user and perform consuming the webservice and returns the appropriate value as per the user input,my need is to show that  resultant value on the first tab of a tabhost.

Comment: Ovidiu Latcu I've used the intent concept but it just showing the answers on another page not in the form of tabhost...thats y i am asking u the code

Comment: As per my knowledge i googled shared preference is recommanded,can you tell how to work with shared preferences on tabhost